# Xcode 6 crashes when clicking source control

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, github

My friend and I have ben using source control and Github to work on our ios app, and now when both of us on either of our computers clicks source control, Xcode crashes.  I have tried setting up a new repository, but nothing works.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the Crash Log:

```html
Process:               Xcode [725]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.1 (6604)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6604000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       752282650
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [725]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2014-11-23 18:06:00.668 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        E84F40F4-8ECA-25F3-C12F-7822DD05B0D4


Time Awake Since Boot: 8100 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A1052d
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6604/IDEKit/SourceControl/CommandHandlers/IDESourceControlWorkingCopyMenuObject.m:181
Details:  workingCopyName should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string
Object:   <IDESourceControlWorkingCopyMenuObject>
Method:   +titleForWorkingCopyName:branchName:dimmingIcons:warningIcon:includeIconInTitles:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8abac389d0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001015259ea -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001002dbd1f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001002dc00e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010177868d +[IDESourceControlWorkingCopyMenuObject titleForWorkingCopyName:branchName:dimmingIcons:warningIcon:includeIconInTitles:] (in IDEKit)
  4  0x000000010177824d +[IDESourceControlWorkingCopyMenuObject titleForWorkingCopyName:branchName:dimmingIcons:includeIconInTitles:] (in IDEKit)
  5  0x0000000101777547 -[IDESourceControlWorkingCopyMenuObject loadMenuItem] (in IDEKit)
  6  0x00000001017786ef -[IDESourceControlWorkingCopyMenuObject menuItem] (in IDEKit)
  7  0x00000001015506b0 -[IDESourceControlMenuDelegate menuWillOpen:] (in IDEKit)
  8  0x00007fff860eeb85 -[NSMenu _sendMenuOpeningNotification] (in AppKit)
  9  0x00007fff85f73002 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonOpenEvent:handlerCallRef:] (in AppKit)
 10  0x00007fff85dba03b NSSLMMenuEventHandler (in AppKit)
 11  0x00007fff8b4ad32c DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) (in HIToolbox)
 12  0x00007fff8b4ac76e SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) (in HIToolbox)
 13  0x00007fff8b4ac5e2 SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions (in HIToolbox)
 14  0x00007fff8b50de37 SendMenuOpening(MenuSelectData*, MenuData*, double, unsigned int, unsigned int, __CFDictionary*, unsigned char, unsigned char*) (in HIToolbox)
 15  0x00007fff8b531fa2 DrawTheMenu(MenuSelectData*, __CFArray**, unsigned char, unsigned char*) (in HIToolbox)
 16  0x00007fff8b531ccc MenuChanged(MenuSelectData*, unsigned char, unsigned char) (in HIToolbox)
 17  0x00007fff8b51e676 TrackMenuCommon(MenuSelectData&, unsigned char*) (in HIToolbox)
 18  0x00007fff8b5317f1 MenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, unsigned int, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) (in HIToolbox)
 19  0x00007fff8b53149e _HandleMenuSelection2 (in HIToolbox)
 20  0x00007fff85d3fe6e _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent (in AppKit)
 21  0x00007fff85bdbb90 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 22  0x00007fff85bdafd0 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 23  0x000000010084682d -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 24  0x00007fff85bcef73 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 25  0x00007fff85bba424 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 26  0x00007fff8986c5c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
![@"" isEqualToString:(workingCopyName)]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b282 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8dd5fb73 abort + 129
2   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001015255c6 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1510
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000101525ba0 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1169
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001002dbd1f _DVTAssertionHandler + 367
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001002dc00e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 407
6   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010177868d +[IDESourceControlWorkingCopyMenuObject titleForWorkingCopyName:branchName:dimmingIcons:warningIcon:includeIconInTitles:] + 1048
7   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010177824d +[IDESourceControlWorkingCopyMenuObject titleForWorkingCopyName:branchName:dimmingIcons:includeIconInTitles:] + 72
8   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000101777547 -[IDESourceControlWorkingCopyMenuObject loadMenuItem] + 922
9   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001017786ef -[IDESourceControlWorkingCopyMenuObject menuItem] + 93
10  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001015506b0 -[IDESourceControlMenuDelegate menuWillOpen:] + 1219
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff860eeb85 -[NSMenu _sendMenuOpeningNotification] + 100
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85f73002 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonOpenEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 28
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85dba03b NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 724
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b4ad32c DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1260
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b4ac76e SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 386
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b4ac5e2 SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 43
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b50de37 SendMenuOpening(MenuSelectData*, MenuData*, double, unsigned int, unsigned int, __CFDictionary*, unsigned char, unsigned char*) + 482
18  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b531fa2 DrawTheMenu(MenuSelectData*, __CFArray**, unsigned char, unsigned char*) + 280
19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b531ccc MenuChanged(MenuSelectData*, unsigned char, unsigned char) + 356
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b51e676 TrackMenuCommon(MenuSelectData&, unsigned char*) + 1211
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b5317f1 MenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, unsigned int, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) + 510
22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b53149e _HandleMenuSelection2 + 446
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85d3fe6e _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 277
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85bdbb90 _DPSNextEvent + 1843
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85bdafd0 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
26  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010084682d -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85bcef73 -[NSApplication run] + 594
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85bba424 NSApplicationMain + 1832
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8986c5c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87c22e kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff85220a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87652e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87569f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1eb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1dfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1d838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8cde3e90 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff895a2b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b3f6 __select + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87652e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87569f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1eb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1dfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1d838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff895a4ab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000010e98c1d2 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 676
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff895a2b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87652e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87569f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1eb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1dfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1d838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85d3e8f7 _NSEventThread + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87652e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87569f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1eb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1dfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1d838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff895a4ab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff896a045f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x00000001116269eb -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff895a2b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:: JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff8b182d2e std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 126
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff82b533fa JSC::BlockAllocator::waitForDuration(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >) + 170
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff82942244 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 84
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff82937a9f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 16:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff8b182c95 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 47
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8294286b JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 171
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff829426c8 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff82937a9f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff8b182c95 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 47
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8294286b JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 171
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff829426c8 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff82937a9f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff8b182c95 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 47
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8294286b JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 171
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff829426c8 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff82937a9f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010b44eefe -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 519
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff895a2b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010b44eefe -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 519
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff895a2b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010b44eefe -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 519
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff895a2b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87652e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87569f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1eb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1dfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ca1d838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8cad3ed1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff8a049b8f SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 463
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8f87b486 __semwait_signal + 10
1   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff8fb46067 0x7fff8fb33000 + 77927
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b2fc _pthread_body + 131
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b2b279 _pthread_start + 176
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff85b294b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff5faf3fe8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000130f  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5faf4010  rsp: 0x00007fff5faf3fe8
   r8: 0x0000000000000fff   r9: 0x00007f8abac389d0  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff8d222ac0  r13: 0x00007f8abe34bde0  r14: 0x00007fff72da8300  r15: 0x00007f8abac21700
  rip: 0x00007fff8f87b282  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff742c5fd8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Comment: Can you post the Xcode crashlog?

Comment: @JAL I just posted the crashllog, well what I could fit on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

removing those from the .xccheckout file fixes the crash:

`IDESourceControlRepositoryExtensionIdentifierKey
public.vcs.git
IDESourceControlWCCIdentifierKey
76200F0D6584D865E96F58DE862E738E88B23A3C
IDESourceControlWCCName`

.xccheckout:

`Foo. xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/Foo.xccheckout`